# Comparing times in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, postman

I have a mechanic schema with two attributes `StartTime` and `EndTime` to set (Working Hours), whenever a user make request to machenic for taking any service, he has to enter time of service.

Now I want to compare time entered by user with time in machenic schema(stored in mongooDB) to check if any mechanic is available between service time entered by user .. **comparing time Especially by taking into account AM and PM** ...

I am using **NODE.JS** , **mongoose** as database and **POSTMAN** for making API requests.

```
var Mechanicschema = new Schema({
startTime: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    endTime: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if it's possible, don't store your `startTime` and `endTime` as a String. Either store them as a Number (Unix timestamp) or as a Date object. Otherwise it would be really difficult to construct a proper query to your database which is the most efficient way to return most relevant results. It also eliminates the need to care about AM or PM.

Assuming that you are storing them as Date objects, and you are exporting a `Mechanics` model of your schema, such as:

```
const Mechanicschema = new Schema(
    {
        startTime: { type: Date, required: true },
        endTime: { type: Date, required: true },
    }
);

const Mechanics = mongoose.model('mechanics', Mechanicschema );

module.exports = Mechanics;
```

you can do the following:

```
const checkMechanic = async(user_date) => {
    // where user_date is expected to be a Date object similar to new Date()
    const results = await Mechanics.find({
        startTime: { $lte: user_date },
        endTime: { $gte: user_date }
    });

    if (results.length > 0) {
        return results;
    }

    return false;
};
```

What will happen here once you call this function is that if no mechanics that are available are found, function will return false, otherwise it will return a list of all mechanics available to perform the task.

You can also substitute `find()` with `findOne` if you only care about the first available result.